# Google Search Results returning links not on my site

Tags: google-search

If you do a Google search for "Colla Voce Music" you can see that the results bring up Cialis, Viagra and Lipitor as pages on the site.  I have searched everywhere and the site itself has not been compromised.  I have searched through the files and the db.  Google Webmaster tools show no malware on the site either.  Where and how can I fix this?  I have uploaded a screenshot of the results. I can't upload images yet, but it is pretty obvious if you do the Google search.

Answer (score 0):

When the googlebot crawled your site, there were links to these items there.  Looking at the URLs underlying the site suggestions, it looks likely these URLs were fed from the DB (see: itemId194).

It's possible you suffered a SQL injection attack at some point which placed these items in your item database.

These URLs will age off eventually, though you can try the Google Webmaster tools removal URL tool to request expedited removal.  See: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Comment: Thanks! I have already searched through my db and did not find any signs.  I submitted the site to be reindexed already, so hopefully that will take care of it.  I will try the removal if the indexing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

At least in one of your pages a viagra product is being offered. Check it out in this url: http://collavoce.com/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=328&Itemid=188

Comment: I don't see it on that page though, or in the source.  Where do you see it?